# Opengl Es - orbit rotation around camera position

Tags: android, opengl-es

I wonder how to solve this problem using opengl on android. I have camera with quaternion, which describes its rotation. I want to have an object f.e. Cube will be in the same screen relative position. So, i want to rotate it and translate around camera position using this quaternion. It is something similiar to crosshair in games, but I dont want to use this for overlay, but for drag drop feature for 3D objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a point in the direction represented by a quaternion at a given distance. For this, you cannot use quaternion directly like you do for vectors.

You can convert quaternion to matrix and then do the same logic as below.

```
glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(rotationQuat);
glm::vec4 newPosition = rotate * vector;
```